# How to send latitude and longitude from Android to Mysql

Tags: android, mysql, android-layout, android-intent

[image]
I am making a simple Android app to get the location of an Android user and I need to send the latitude and longitude to the MySQL database. How can I do that with this kind of code segment?

DatabaseHandler class

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gps";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "location";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_LAT = "lat";
    private static final String KEY_LONG = "long";

     public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_LAT + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LONG + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new values
    void addvalues(LatLong value) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_LAT, value.get_lat()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_LONG,  value.get_long()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


}
```

My log cat

```
12-30 13:59:49.040: D/gralloc_goldfish(1411): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-30 13:59:50.960: D/GPS Enabled(1411): GPS Enabled
12-30 13:59:50.980: D/AndroidRuntime(1411): Shutting down VM
12-30 13:59:50.980: W/dalvikvm(1411): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a6aba8)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): Process: com.example.gpstracking, PID: 1411
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$1.onClick(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:46)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-30 13:59:50.990: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 13:59:55.950: I/Process(1411): Sending signal. PID: 1411 SIG: 9
```

here is my GPSTracker class

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is my Android Activity

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnShowLocation;

    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem, you are facing?

Comment: from this code segment i am getting latitude and longitude in a dialog correctly.but i want know how i can pass them to the Mysql database.i have written a php script also.

Comment: hi .do you have the table created in in your local database or do you have any service to send it to the mysql db.here there are two ways we can do .let me know clearly so that i can give you sample example.

Comment: @ManiTeja yes i have created my table in local database

Comment: @ManiTeja I have update the my log cat please have alook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

Step 1 Create the following class LatLong.java:

```
public class LatLong {
    
    //private variables
    int _id;
    String _lat;
    String _long;
    

    // Empty constructor
    public LatLong(){
        
    }
    // constructor
    public LatLong(int id, String latitude, String longitude){
        this._id = id;
        this._lat = latitude;
        this._long = longitude;
    }
    
    // constructor
    public LatLong(String latitude, String longitude){
        this._lat = latitude;
        this._long = longitude;
    }
    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }
    
    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }
    
    public String get_lat() {
        return _lat;
    }
    public void set_lat(String _lat) {
        this._lat = _lat;
    }
    public String get_long() {
        return _long;
    }
    public void set_long(String _long) {
        this._long = _long;
    }

}
```

Step 2: Create the following db class:DatabaseHandler.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;


import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gps";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "gracking";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_LAT = "lat";
    private static final String KEY_LONG = "long";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_LAT + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LONG + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new values
    void addvalues(LatLong value) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_LAT, value.get_lat()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_LONG,  value.get_long()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


}
```

Step 3: Add the following code in your class:

```
 btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();


  DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        
        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting latlongs
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addvalues(new LatLong("latvalue", "longvalue"));

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: at my Main class im getting an error saying that "The constructor DatabaseHandler(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined" as suggest i have create super onclistner then also gives me same error.

Comment: no need create .Did you created the db class what i had given.

Comment: import DatabaseHandler  into your main class.dont create any other things.It is the basic issue boss.you need to think once

Comment: can you send me your  class once.did you created as what i had given DatabaseHandler.java.Try this   inside the activity.DatabaseHandler db;in on click. db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

Comment: update your activityclass.where u are getting error.that class

Comment: i have update my activity class but same problem.I have upload an image (link)please see

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the  latitude and longitude to your server by http protocol,that is you should use network connection frameworks like Volley or OKHttp to connect your server and send this information to your server,then your server can get the  latitude and longitude and update it to Mysql database,you can't write it to your Mysql database directly.

Since you have got correct data,afterwards you only do following two things:
1. write a function that receives latitude and longitude as parameter,to write this data to your mysql database. 
2. use Volley or OKHttp or other network communication utils you're familiar to send latitude and longitude to your php script(has done in step1).For example,if you use Volley,you can refer this [doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/volley/request.html).

Comment: any examples plzzzzzzz

Comment: @joseph,sorry,I don't know how your database is designed,so I can't give your concrete code,but I can give you the step to make it.Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code to insert lat,log in local database.

// show location button click event

```
       btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
SQLiteDatabase dbm = this.getWritableDatabase();
                 ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();


                cv.put("LAT_G",
                        gps.getLatitude());

                cv.put("LANG",  gps.getLongitude());

                boolean result = dbm.insert("table name", cv);


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
```

Note:Need to create your dbm instance as per your logic

Comment: when i try this code i have some log cat errors and application has stopped and actually i am new to android how can i create dbm instance

Comment: how you created the db structure .Let me know .or let me know the error what you are getting.so that i can help you

Comment: database name is gps. and table name is location.there are three fields id which is auto incremented and other two fields are latitude and longitude(double).

Comment: i have update the log cat please have a look.error occurs when i click the button

Comment: hi  use the code what i posted 2 time . i tested this code it is working fine for insertion.

Comment: hi insted of this use your classname.this once

Comment: yep now progrmme is running smootly. but there ara no values stord in the database.is it must to have a php script for that??

Comment: In which database.is the values stored in local database first.if it is saved then righ the logic to sync records to server

Comment: I want to save these values at locally created mysql database.but right now its not stored.

Comment: boss it is storing  in the sqlite locally created. not  able to understand where you need to save the values.if you want to save the values in mysql  you need to create your service and pass the stored values to the my sql it will work.

Comment: sorry for disturbing u this much.is it k to do that with json?

Comment: yes.json means you can send the data to mysql using json object or xml .or in json that depends on your requirement.